# Convert Combobox to Textbox in Gridview C#

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

i have an combobox cell and i wanna convert to textbox cell after select item from the same combobox cell and convert to textbox but the problem when using

[1, DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()`

the cell not change until click on another cell although i'm using `Datagridview1.refresh()`

[the first picture (when select from combobox then it should be changed )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGQXp.jpg)

[the second picture ( after click an another cell )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnxLJ.jpg)

Comment: Your question is lacking details and it would be difficult to help. Add more details. Read the tips on adding a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: questions seems clear to me but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type.. ComboBoxes in DGVs are __notoriously bad__ at grasping when the edit is really done. There are highly convoluted ways and then one can move currentcell to another cell and back..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridViewComboBoxCells` are notoriously obtuse when it comes to such a simple thing as simply and fully accepting a selected value..

This seems to work for me:

```
ComboBox editComboBox = null;

private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
                           DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is ComboBox && e.ColumnIndex == 1)
    {
        editComboBox = (ComboBox)e.Control;
        editComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted -= editComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted;
        editComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += editComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted;
    }
}

void editComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView1[1, dataGridView5.CurrentRow.Index] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    DataGridView1[1, dataGridView5.CurrentRow.Index].Value =
                        editComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

    DataGridView1.EndEdit();
    DataGridView1[1, dataGridView5.CurrentRow.Index]cell1.Selected = false;
    editComboBox = null;
}
```

Note that calling [`EndEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) allegedly can raise an exception if no error handler is found. I don't have one and I still don't get an error. Not sure what the docs mean; maybe that it may raise an error if the data are in fact invalid..

Also note that with this design the user can not easily correct an edit, unless you provide a way to restore the dropdown..